# How to validate specific action using XML configuration in Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I want to validate specific method only in action class.
Action method is this.

```java
public String add() throws Exception {

// aflag = true;

org.setAoName(aoName);
orgBo.addOrg(org);
orglist = orgBo.searchOrg(organisationSearch);
setAoName("");
setAflag("viewaddorgs");

return "add";
}
```

Problem is currently I have many action methods in action class. When I call those methods it validate this method. Please help me to validate only this method by XML.

**This is my `OraganisationAction-validation.xml`:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">

<validators>

    <field name="aoName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                The name is required!
            </message>
        </field-validator>
        
        <field-validator type="requiredfield">
            <message>
                The name is required!
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>


</validators>
```

**This is my JSP :**

```jsp
    <s:form id="post" action="addorgs" validate="true" >

    <s:textfield name="aoName" label="Add Organisations"  />

</s:form>
```

**`struts xml` :**

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">


        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        
        <action name="*security" class="com.ast.action.admin.SecurityAction"
            method="{1}">
            <result name="second" type="tiles">secondTemplate</result>
            <result name="pass" type="tiles">orgTemplate</result>
        </action>


        <action name="*orgs" class="com.ast.action.admin.OraganisationAction"
            method="{1}">
            
            <result name="viewadd" type="tiles">orgAddTemplate</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">orgAddTemplate</result>
            <result name="add" type="tiles">orgAddTemplate</result>
            <result name="addtbl" type="tiles">orgAddTemplate</result>
            <result name="search" type="tiles">orgTemplate</result>
            <result name="delete" type="tiles">orgTemplate</result>
            <result name="viewedit" type="tiles">orgEditTemplate</result>
            <result name="edit" type="tiles">orgEditTemplate</result>
            <result name="edittbl" type="tiles">orgEditTemplate</result>
            <result name="orgmenu" type="tiles">orgTemplate</result>
            <result name="view" type="tiles">orgViewTemplate</result>
        </action>
```

it works with annotations but with XML no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use an action alias: map different methods of an Action to different action aliases in struts.xml, and instead of the single `yourAction-validation.xml` file, add a `yourAction-yourAlias-validation.xml` for the validators you want to perform for that method only.

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23784739/1654265).

**EDIT**

> No its not validation anything now.
>
> ```xml
> <validators> 
>     <field name="aoName">
>         <field-validator type="required"> 
>             <message>You cannot leave the aoName address field empty.</message>
>         </field-validator> 
>     </field>
> </validators>
> ```
>
> name is `OraganisationAction-add-validation.xml` and put it with action class package. Is there anything to enable validation in struts.xml ?

If you have a correctly configured (for example the default) Interceptor Stack, validation is already enabled. If you are using a file named `OraganisationAction-add-validation.xml`, that means that:

- your action CLASS must be named `OraganisationAction.java`;
- your action mapping in struts.xml must be the following:

  ```xml
  <action name="add" class="your.package.OraganisationAction" method="add">
      <result>yourResult.jsp</result>
  </action>
  ```

Look for typos, check your Interceptor Stack, and it will work automatically.

Comment: Can you tell me where to put this file.
Same place where struts.xml resides(Resources folder)?

Comment: Beside (or in place of) your existing action-validation.xml file (that is beside your Action class). Since the validation file must match the Action name, [you can map different "actions" each one to a method for the same Action class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13343982/1654265), you can map them with alias validation files.

Comment: No its not validation anything now.
<validators>
 <field name="aoName">
  <field-validator type="required">
   <message>You cannot leave the aoName address field empty.</message>
  </field-validator>
 </field>
</validators>
name is OraganisationAction-add-validation.xml and put it with action class package.
Is there anything to enable validation in struts.xml

Comment: @Dilis Have you read the updated answer ? Have you tried ? Did it work ?

Comment: No. May be im using tiles and struts jquery plugin to submit form

Answer (score 0):

To exclude some methods from validation you can override parameters of the `validation` interceptor. For example in interceptor stack you can write

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
  <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,yourmethod</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

in the action configuration you can use above code and

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
  <param name="validation.excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,yourmethod</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Note `yourmethod` is a method name.

You can specify a `validation.xml` for only one action by a postfix of action name in this file.  For example `AcrionClass-add-validation.xml` will work only for the action name `add` in the action config. Note here `add` is an action name, not a method name.

> Often, the name attribute matches the method name, but they may also differ.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems but then these are couple of things that i rectified :

1) DOCTYPE in the yourAction-yourAlias-validation.xml should be

```
    <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

2)Created a custom interceptor to exclude the methods that need not be validated.Below is a sample for my candidate registration where i had to skip validation for district method which fetched districts for a state.

```
 <interceptor-stack name="clientValidation">
  <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
   <interceptor-ref name="validation">
     <param name="excludeMethods">input,district</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
  <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
</interceptor-stack>


<package name="registration" namespace="/candidate" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="candidateRegistration" class="com.app.action.CandidateAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="clientValidation"/>
                <result name="input">/jsps/student/studentregistration.jsp</result>
                <result name="failure1">/jsps/student/registrationfailure.jsp</result>
                <result name="cancelRegistration">/jsps/login.jsp</result>
                <result name="district">/jsps/includes/dropdown_districts_regoffice.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
```

Comment: Still not validating method