# Struts2 Action class validate method

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, ognl

Trying to use validate method on Struts 2.3.4 but got below error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at com.action.LogonAction.validate(LogonAction.java:66)
>   more......

**Action class:**

```
public class LogonAction extends ActionSupport{

private Logon logon;

public Logon getLogon() {
    return logon;
}

public void setLogon(Logon logon) {
    this.logon = logon;
}

public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}

public void validate(){
    if(logon.getUserName() == null  || logon.getUserName().equals("")){
        addFieldError("logon.userName", "userName required");
    }

}
```

**Logon.class:**

```
public class Logon {

private String password;
private String userName;


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<struts>

<package name="struts2" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="login" class="com.action.LogonAction">
        <result name="input">Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

**jsp:**

```jsp
<s:form action="login" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User name:<s:textfield name="userName"/>
    <tr>
        <td><s:submit type="button" value="submit" label="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</s:form>
```

Is there any way to fix this other than using the new version of Struts2?
Because I found one post said that Struts 2.3.4 have validate method bug.

Comment: you should use struts2 Model Driven arch see here http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/ & since parameters are null its throwing error

Comment: @goodyzain **No.** One should not.

Comment: You have `logon.getUserName()` in action but in jsp just `userName`. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `NullPointerException` in the code below

```java
if(logon.getUserName() == null  || logon.getUserName().equals("")){
```

this can only happen if `logon` is `null`.

---

If you have only one action in the action class that populates properties from the submitted form, you can just bind the input controls to action class properties via OGNL.

```jsp
<s:form action="login" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User name:<s:textfield name="logon.userName" />
    <tr>
        <td><s:submit type="button" value="submit" label="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Here, `logon.userName` is OGNL expression that evaluates to render a `value` of the textfield. Unless you explicitly specify a `value` attribute the expression is called.

It uses a call `getLogon().getUserName()` on the action instance. Since you didn't initialize the `logon` property before the result is executed then it will throw another `NullPointerException` but it's caught internally and ignored. The texttfield tag renders nothing in this case. And you might feel that it works!?

Because when you submit the form it uses a value from the `name` attribute of the textfield and passes it as a request parameter. This parameter name then parses for OGNL. It's the same OGNL expression `logon.userName`, but Struts will use `getLogon().setUserName()` on the action instance to set the value of the parameter.

The reasonable question why it doesn't throw exception, i.e. why the call to `getLogon()` returns a `Logon` instance? This is Struts2 magic. It can handle `null` values between calls `getLogon()` and `setUserName()`. By default it creates an object if it's not yet created. You can control this behavior using a constant in `struts.xml`.

But, in my point of view you should create it yourself or with the container that has DI, that provides the beans configuration like Spring.

---

### Easy fixing solution:

```java
private Logon logon = new Logon();
```

Struts2 mostly used to map many actions to the same action class and not only to `execute` method. Thus having a bean initialized will safely keep you of the errors reproduced internally or externally when actions are called.

Comment: Thanks,This fix the problem. But now the error message display before I submit the form. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: You should have two actions, one that shows a login page, another that handle a submittion, the one that shows should be excluded from validation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36358850/573032